# Reference another Table in the Query Editor (PowerBI or PowerQuery)

Tags: powerbi, powerquery, m

I am running a query to update a historical data table within PowerBI. This update query calls the Adobe Analytics API, and pulls data based on a date range I specify.

As I want this to run as fast as possible, I would only like to query the data that I don't already have in my historical data table. I am okay at putting an end date for this query based off Date.Time.LocalNow().

```
#date(Date.Year(DateTime.LocalNow()), Date.Month(DateTime.LocalNow()), Date.Day(DateTime.LocalNow())-1)
```

However, where I am stuck is putting a start date. Ideally I would like to take the MaxDate from a table within my data model, and use this value in the query editor as my start date.

How would I do this?

**UPDATE 1 - Full code Below**

```
let
Source = AdobeAnalytics.Cubes()
myreportsuiteid = Source{[Id="myreportsuiteid"]}[Data],
#"Added Items" = Cube.Transform(myreportsuiteid,
    {
        {Cube.AddAndExpandDimensionColumn, "DateGranularity", {"year", "month", "day"}, {"Date Granularity.Level 1: Year", "Date Granularity.Level 2: Month", "Date Granularity.Level 3: Day"}},
        {Cube.AddAndExpandDimensionColumn, "lasttouchchannel", {"lasttouchchannel"}, {"Last Touch Marketing Channel"}},        
        {Cube.AddMeasureColumn, "Unique Visitors", "uniquevisitors"},
        {Cube.AddMeasureColumn, "Visits", "visits"},
        {Cube.ApplyParameter, "DateRange", {#date(Date.Year(List.Max(Union[Date])), Date.Month(List.Max(Union[Date])), Date.Day(List.Max(Union[Date]))+1), #date(Date.Year(DateTime.LocalNow()), Date.Month(DateTime.LocalNow()), Date.Day(DateTime.LocalNow())-1)}},
        {Cube.ApplyParameter, "Segment", {{"s300000554_5ae201be22fa9950dcdbcd92"}}}
    })
in
    #"Added Items"
```

**UPDATE 2**

**WORKING CODE**

Daily US is a table created thorough the Query Editor

```
let
Source = AdobeAnalytics.Cubes(),
todaysDate = Date.AddDays(DateTime.Date(DateTime.LocalNow()),-1),
maxDate = Date.AddDays(List.Max(#"Daily US"[Date]),1),
myreportsuiteid = Source{[Id="myreportsuiteid "]}[Data],
```

**ERROR CODE**

Union US is a table created outside of the Query Editor via *Union US = DISTINCT(UNION('Seeker US','Daily US'))*

```
let
Source = AdobeAnalytics.Cubes(),
todaysDate = Date.AddDays(DateTime.Date(DateTime.LocalNow()),-1),
maxDate = Date.AddDays(List.Max(#"Union US"[Date]),1),
myreportsuiteid = Source{[Id="myreportsuiteid "]}[Data],
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the column you want to reference for the `MaxDate` is named `Union[Date]`, then you should be able to use `List.Max` to get the maximum value from that column.

Try this:

```
let
Source = AdobeAnalytics.Cubes(),
MaxDate = List.Max(Union[Date]),
TodaysDate = DateTime.Date(DateTime.LocalNow()),
myreportsuiteid = Source{[Id="myreportsuiteid"]}[Data],
#"Added Items" = Cube.Transform(myreportsuiteid,
    {
        {Cube.AddAndExpandDimensionColumn, "DateGranularity", {"year", "month", "day"}, {"Date Granularity.Level 1: Year", "Date Granularity.Level 2: Month", "Date Granularity.Level 3: Day"}},
        {Cube.AddAndExpandDimensionColumn, "lasttouchchannel", {"lasttouchchannel"}, {"Last Touch Marketing Channel"}},        
        {Cube.AddMeasureColumn, "Unique Visitors", "uniquevisitors"},
        {Cube.AddMeasureColumn, "Visits", "visits"},
        {Cube.ApplyParameter, "DateRange", {MaxDate, TodaysDate}},
        {Cube.ApplyParameter, "Segment", {{"s300000554_5ae201be22fa9950dcdbcd92"}}}
    })
in
    #"Added Items"
```

Comment: Hey Alexis, thanks for the help. I'm a little stuck though with the syntax. Do I need to add the table I want to reference to the query as a Source? I've updated my question to include my full code. The Table I want to reference is call 'Union' (a distinct union between two of my queries). The column is called 'Date'.

Comment: You should be able to reference other queries that are loaded in the query editor. I'd recommend defining variables for both dates, rather than repeatedly referencing them. See my edit.

Comment: Thanks for the variable suggestion and the code cleanup. Will mark your answer as correct. I do have a followup question though - Is there anyway to reference a new table that I have created out of the Query Editor via a Union?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what you're asking. You can reference any table that you have loaded in the query editor whether they're directly from a database or joined from multiple other tables.

Comment: The code works correctly when I reference another table that has been created through the Query Editor, however when I switch it over to my Union table which I created though this line outside of the Query Editor "Union US = DISTINCT(UNION('Seeker US','Daily US'))" I get this error "Expression.Error: The import Union US matches no exports. Did you miss a module reference?"

Comment: Ah, I see what you mean. No, you can't reference calculated columns or calculated tables that were created with DAX. You can, however, create the distinct union of those two inside of the query editor by appending the two tables together and removing duplicates (Remove Rows > Remove Duplicates).

Comment: You're a legend - not sure why I didnt think of that. Haha. Will make the changes on my end. Thanks so much for the help!!